# Polymer with angularjs ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, polymer

I'm trying to integrate polymer in my angularjs project. I made a very simple `paper-dropdown-menu` and i need to get the value of item selected to pass it in a function in my controller. I tried in this way with no results

```
<template id="Demo" is="dom-bind">
        <paper-dropdown-menu name="simple-test">
            <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="0">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[modes]]" as="view">
                    <paper-item data-ng-click="selectedMod(view)">[[view]]</paper-item>
                </template>
            </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
    </template>

<script>
    Demo.modes = [
        'First',
        'Second',
        'Third'
    ];

</script>
```

And in the controller i have the function

```
$scope.selectedMod = function(value) {
  console.log(value)
};
```

But when i click the item nothing happens. Is it possible do this way?

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing a few things in your code. To start with, components are created within the `<dom-module>` tag.

Secondly, in the `<script> </script>`, you need to initialize `Polymer`. Here's an example from the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview.html):

```
<dom-module id="element-name">

  <template>
    <style>
      /* CSS rules for your element */
    </style>

    <!-- local DOM for your element -->

    <div>{{greeting}}</div> <!-- data bindings in local DOM -->
  </template>

  <script>
    // element registration
    Polymer({
      is: "element-name",

      // add properties and methods on the element's prototype

      properties: {
        // declare properties for the element's public API
        greeting: {
          type: String,
          value: "Hello!"
        }
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

---

It also looks like you're [binding data](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding) of type `Array`. This is how you do it:

```
<script>
Polymer({
      is: '<your-element-name>',
      properties: {
        modes: {
          type: Array,
          value = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
       }
     }
})
</script>
```

Comment: `dom-bind` doesn't need an element (dom-module)

Comment: Can you please show me how can i do it using my code? I also tried in that way but maybe i was wrong with something.. thanks

Comment: @End.Game Updated answer

Comment: @ComputerFellow ok but how then i call selectedMod(view) function?

Comment: @End.Game having defined `data-ng-click="selectedMod(view)"` for that element, I'd suspect Angular would handle it normally?

Comment: @ComputerFellow nope.. it isn't called. I think the problem is the "template". I think the template tag neutralize the angular functions. is it possible?

Comment: @End.Game Yes, likely -- since your `ng-app` is outside this component and this is just Shadow DOM. I'd advise against mixing the two libraries together.

Comment: mmh is it possible "include" ng-app in the component or something like that? I need use both right now